# Basic Fancybox Implementation

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox-3

I have been unable to get a basic jquery fancybox to work. I tried working from the documentation on the fancybox website (http://fancybox.net/howto), a tutorial on a separate website (http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/jquery-plugins/jquery-fancybox.php), and I tried browsing a few other related posts to check for common issues ([Basic "jquery fancybox"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702215/basic-jquery-fancybox)), ([Fancybox not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155370/fancybox-not-working)), ([FancyBox not working at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077538/fancybox-not-working-at-all)).

I feel that there is something simple I am overlooking. I call jquery with a CDN before calling fancybox. I have a link to the fancybox css file. I have tried moving the script call to fancybox around inside the head and body tags.

I have tested that jquery works with an alert function which fired successfully. The fancybox css and js files are in the same directory as my html file and images. Below is my trimmed down HTML I am currently testing with no success.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE Html>
<html>
    <head>       
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="jquery.fancybox.css" />
        <script src="jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>       
        <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="BigNewLogo.png"><img src="newLogo.PNG"></a>
        <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="BigNewLogo.png"><img src="newLogo.PNG"></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

The result is the same behavior as excluding fancybox. It displays the small images and when you click on them you are taken away from the page to view the large image.

Update:
The following error appears in the console log:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function
    at jquery.fancybox.js:2659
    at jquery.fancybox.js:2661
(anonymous) @ jquery.fancybox.js:2659
(anonymous) @ jquery.fancybox.js:2661
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Any errors in your console at all?

Comment: I should have thought to look at that. Yes it did show an error: jquery.fancybox.js:2659 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function
    at jquery.fancybox.js:2659
    at jquery.fancybox.js:2661

Comment: Are you using the latest version of jQuery?

Comment: No; I was using 1.4. I changed this to 3.1.1 and it worked. Thanks, Daniel! (Is there a way for me to mark your comment as the answer?)

Comment: No problem, if you can't upvote my comment then don't worry about it. Make sure you mark your answer as correct though so it's seen as resolved. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In those situations you should always look at developer console for any clue. In your case, the message says:

> TypeError: $(...).on is not a function

What it means is that function "on" does not exist. The jQuery documentation - http://api.jquery.com/on/ - says that

> version added: 1.7

So, you would need jQuery version higher than 1.7 to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using jquery v1.4 (similar to the guide on the fancybox website). Changing this to jquery 3.1.1 fixed the problem.